# Load new component while adding href to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, react-state-management

I am trying to implement a system to when an item in the navbar is clicked it loads a new component on the screen. I am running into a problem making this a new URL and keeping my state. Let me clarify.

Here is my navbar code:

```
<Nav pullRight activeKey="1" onSelect={k => this.handleSelect(k)}>
  <NavItem eventKey={1} href={'/component1'}>
    Component 1
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2} href={'/component2'}>
    Component 2
  </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Here is my handleSelect code:

```
handleSelect(eventKey, event) {
     this.setState({
         componentToLoad: eventKey
     });
     event.preventDefault();
 }
```

In my render I do this:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.componentToLoad === 'component1'){
        return (<Component1/>);
    } else if(this.props.componentToLoad === 'component2'){
        return (<Component2/>);
}
```

The problem I'm running into is because of the href adding to the URL the page reloads and I lose my state so it always loads component 1 because I set it to that in the constructor. If I remove the href it works, but the URL is not how I want it.

How do I get this to load the component I want, add to the URL, and keep the state?

Thank you

Comment: Use a react router. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) is a good choice for your requirements.
[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxmvl662mj) using React Router, simply illustrating the functionality you describe.

You could also use the browser's [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (see pushState method) to manipulate the URL directly without a page reload, although be aware that there are [some differences in the api in modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History#Browser_compatibility).